# Does Executioner work on spells?

Tags: league-of-legends

[Executioner](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Executioner) is the last ability in the OFFENSE mastery tree.  It states:

> Increases damage dealt by 6% to targets below 40% Health.

Does this refer to attack damage only, spell damage only, or both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes Executioner works with spells and more:

> The additional 6% to targets below 40% is confirmed to proc on
>   summoner spells, abilities and physical attacks. Does not work with
>   Smite.

[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Executioner)

Comment: I couldn't find any videos or RIOT reports on this. But if you check most of the Spotlights of mages, You'll see that Phreak (Riot staff) uses Executioner as Mastery.

Comment: Occam's razor applies too - it doesn't mention *not* working with spells... so why wouldn't it?

Answer (score 3):

As you'll notice, **the OFFENSE mastery page includes buffs to AP and AD stats.**

Riot could have made things clearer but the overall answer is yes.

**Enemies below 40% HP will receive 6% more magic damage AND normal attack damage.**